# Parsing binary data

Tags: parsing, antlr

I got interested in parser generators. But I don't have the theoretical background. I just read a few things on the internet.

Currently I'm trying to do something with ANTLR

So my questions:

I have a special format of my dataframes:

- The first byte of a frame is a tag that describes the nature of the data
- The second byte contains the length (number of bytes) of the data itself
- Then follows the data itself
- The data can contain dataframes itself, and dataframes can be listed one after the other

I hope my description is clear. My questions:

Can I create such a parser with ANTLR that reads the lengs of the frame and then knows when the frame ends?

In ANTLR can I load the different tags I use from a generated file?

Thank you!

Comment: Sory if I wasn't clear. I have a generated file, that define the meaning of the tags. I don't need it for the parsing itself. Because I know from the length field when a new tag begins. And I'ts all binary data. Just a bunch of bytes. I'ts a file format for a embedded system, thats why it is so compact and not human readable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but:

- Parser generators like antlr require a grammar that is at least context-free
- using length-fields in your data makes your grammar not context free (context-sensitive i think)

It is the latter point i'm not sure about - maybe you want to research some more on that.

You probably have to write a packet "parser" yourself (which then has to be a parser for your context-sensitive packet grammar)

Alternatively, you could drop the length field, and use something like s-expressions, JSON or xml; these would be parseable by something generated with antlr.

Comment: No, the grammar ANTLR uses to create a lexer and/or parser can be context sensitive w.r.t. both parser- (production) and lexer- (terminal) rules.

Comment: -1, although the accepted answer, it contains incorrect information.

Comment: @BartKiers I'm just curious, can you explain or provide a link then?

Comment: @SLin in ANTLR you can use predicates to "drive" certain parses (i.e. context sensitive parsing). More (technical) info can be found here: http://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be better off to create a hand written binary parser instead of using ANTLR because ANTLR is primarily intended to read and make sense of a text file and not binary data. The lexer part is focused on tokenizing text so trying to make it read binary data instead would be an uphill battle.

It sounds as if your structure would need some kind of recursive way of reading the data although it could be done easier just having a tree structure and then fill it as you read your file.

Comment: Ok I thought that ANTLR would be overkill... But it's an interesting topic. And I'd like to learn more about parser generators. But I'll give it a try if I have a more suitable task for it. Thanks